# Using Hive with Riverpod, not sure what to load during loading phase

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, riverpod, flutter-hive

I am trying to learn how to use `Hive` for local storage and `Riverpod` for state managment in my flutter app.

```
final _localStorageProvider = FutureProvider<Box>(
  (ref) async  {
    final appDocumentDir = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    Hive
      ..init(appDocumentDir.path)
      ..registerAdapter(QuizOptionModelAdapter());
    return Hive.openBox(keys.localStorageBoxKey);
  }
);

final _localDataSourceProvider = Provider<QuestionLocalDataSourceImpl>(
      (ref) => QuestionLocalDataSourceImpl(
          uploadQuestionBox: ref.watch(_localStorageProvider).maybeWhen(
        data:(d) => d,
        error:(e, trace) {
          print("***************************");
          print(e);
          print(trace);
          print("***************************");
          throw Exception("FAILED");
        },
        orElse: () => throw Exception("OR ELSE")
      ),
  ),
);
```

My problem is, I am not sure what other return value I can use during `error` & `orElse` phase other than exceptions. Since I am using exception, very briefly before the actual page loads, I get an ugly error page as shown in the screenshot, which disappers in 1 second  after the actual elements are rendered.

Any help to avoid throwing  errors during `error` & `orElse` phase would be really helpful.

So far have tried these solutions without any luck

```
final _localDataSourceProvider = Provider<QuestionLocalDataSourceImpl>(
      (ref) => QuestionLocalDataSourceImpl(
          uploadQuestionBox: ref.watch(_localStorageProvider).maybeWhen(
        data:(d) => d,
        orElse: () => AsyncValue.loading() as Box
      ),
  ),
);
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hello there, your implementation is error prone. What I can answer is another aproach without those errors but I'm not sure if you want to keep the same implementation or look for another.

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is that you try to deal with `error` and `orElse` *within* the `Provider`. A more common way to do this is to `watch` the `FutureProvider` within a Widget's `build` method, and to render a proper data Widget if the data from the `FutureProvider` is available, and another Widget if the data is not yet available (`loading`) or if there is an error. That way, all three cases of the `Provider`'s `when` method return the same type: a `Widget`.

From the `Riverpod` docs, see this example:

```
final configurationsProvider = FutureProvider<Configuration>((ref) async {
  final uri = Uri.parse('configs.json');
  final rawJson = await File.fromUri(uri).readAsString();

  return Configuration.fromJson(json.decode(rawJson));
});

class Example extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final configs = ref.watch(configurationsProvider);

    // Use Riverpod's built-in support
    // for error/loading states using "when":
    return configs.when(
      loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
      error: (err, stack) => Text('Error $err'),
      data: (configs) => Text('data: ${configs.host}'),
    );
  }
}
```

In your case, if you want to retain the `_localDataSourceProvider` then my suggestion would be to make that also a `FutureProvider` that 'wraps' the `_localStorageProvider`, and to watch the `_localDataSourceProvider` within the `build` method of the Widget where you render the data.  *There*, you can use the `.when(...)` clauses for `loading` (for example to show a `CircularProgressIndicator` until the data is loaded), `data` to render the data, and if necessary `error` to capture any errors that `Hive` may generate through the `FutureProvider`.